# Why is the MSI message data always 0? And how does IRQ affinity work?

Tags: linux-kernel, x86, interrupt, pci

So my wireless network controller uses MSI:

```
$ grep iwlwifi /proc/interrupts
 127:    6853702      26739       9382          0  IR-PCI-MSI-0000:02:00.0    0-edge      iwlwifi
```

Looking at the output of `sudo lspci -vvvxxx -s 02:00.0` I see this:

```
        Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
                Address: 00000000fee002f8  Data: 0000
```

I don't understand why the "Data" part is 0. This is supposed to encode the interrupt vector and other information, right? Also bits 12-19 of the address are supposed to represent the destination ID, but those are 0 too.

How does changing the IRQ affinity work? If I change the value of `/proc/irq/127/smp_affinity` and then look at `/proc/interrupts` again, I see that the IRQ is migrated successfully. However, if I look at the output of `lspci` again, nothing has changed in the MSI address nor data. How does IRQ affinity work on x86 Linux? I expected the MSI address to change.

Also, I checked other MSI (not MSI-X) enabled devices in my x86 laptop and the case is always the same. The data is always 0, and the destination ID part of the address it's always 0 too. I checked another laptop and it's the same there too.

So my questions are:

- Why is the MSI data always 0 for every device?
- Why is the destination ID part of the MSI address always 0 for every device?
- How does IRQ affinity work? What happens when I change the `smp_affinity` value?
- Where is the interrupt vector really encoded?

And bonus question:

- Where does the IRQ 127 number come from in this case? Is that number completely different to the real interrupt vector?

Comment: If this is an Intel system, probably interrupt remapping is enabled in the IOMMU. When interrupt remapping is enabled, the interrupt handle is in bits 19:5 of the address. The data is called the sub handle, and it is typically zero, as you see.  Interrupt affinity is changed by changing the interrupt remapping table in the IOMMU without changing  the MSI programming in the device. See the Intel VT-d spec at [this site](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/intel-sdm.html). It is called "Intel® Virtualization Technology for Directed I/O Architecture Specification"

Comment: @prl Of course, I completely forgot about interrupt remapping! Thanks!